# Google maps touch device click event on overlay stop propagate to map event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events, event-handling

I have google map and some overlay.
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ba8c5xat/)

Map has registered click Listener and overlay div has registered click DomListener.

When I click on over div, I do not want event to be propagated to map. I'm using `event.stopPropagation`. All works with mouse.

But when I switch to some touch device - using chrome dev tools, both events are called.

How can I stop this propagation?

Comment: Check this SO question [11994833](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994833/event-preventdefault-not-canceling-link-direction-in-jquery-mobile) and [14530734](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530734/handle-both-mouse-and-touch-events-on-touch-screens) if it can help you.

Comment: hello @Vlado can you please update solution here

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47863475/how-to-stoppropagation-of-touch-event-on-overlay-googlemap