# How to stopPropagation of touch event on overlay GoogleMap

Tags: javascript, google-maps

You can find out code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ba8c5xat/). I tried with global & local event both

```
event.preventDefault()
event.stopPropagation()
event.returnValue = false
event.cancelBubble = true;
```

above code working fine for mouse click events but for touch event map still receives click events.

Comment: You've spelled `cancelBubble` incorrectly.

Comment: Thanx, I wrote correct cancelBubble there but still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a listener to `touchend` event, so you can stop the propagation of this event:

```
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function(e) {
      console.log("over click");
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      clickOverlay();
  })

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "touchend", function(e) {
      console.log("over touchend");
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      clickOverlay();
  })
```

Here is your fiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/xx1ycd7L/